# Encoding in 8 Bit Integer to Text in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I updating a script to Python 3 from Python 2 and having trouble with the line below, it decodes and displays the RSSI value of a BLE Beacon:

```
rssi = struct.unpack("b", packet[packetOffset -1])
```

I found an alternative method to get the same result, which takes the 2 last characters in the broadcast string and converts them to text. Using an 8 Bit Signed Integer Encoder.

For example `c3` becomes `-61` (https://cryptii.com/pipes/integer-encoder)

However I am struggling to find a way to do this in python 3!

How do I decode the string?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us tha string?

Comment: Did you notice that `int('c3', 16)` -> `195` and accidentally `195 - 256 = -61`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
a = bytes.fromhex('c3')

res = a[0] - 256 if a[0] > 127 else a[0]
```

`bytes.fromhex` takes a string and transforms it to a `byte` object. You take the first byte and make it unsigned by checking whether it's greater than 127.

Alternatively:

```
res = int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex('c3'), byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

Comment: Yes! Is there a big difference if I used 'num = int('c3', 16) - 256' instead?

Comment: There is. If you try `int('0f', 16) - 256` you get `-241`. You need to check whether the value is >127 or not. Using `int` is a good idea. Not sure of the consequences. I need to think about it.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Why the a[0] has to to be smaller than 127 to keep it's natural decimal representation. Can you elaborate on that? I have trouble to understand it.

Comment: @Marcin The OP requires a signed integer encoder but as far as I remember ``bytes.fromhex`` returns a list of unsigned byte. The test to see whether ``a[0] > 127`` is just offsets the value to a signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown exactly what's in `packet`, but here's a guess:

```
import struct


packet = b'\x00\xc3\x00\xff'
packetOffset = 2

rssi = struct.unpack("b", packet[packetOffset-1: packetOffset])[0]
print(repr(rssi))  # -> -61

# For a text string result, just do:
rssi = str(rssi)
print(repr(rssi))  # -> '-61'
```